# Getting video from image sequence of figures with subplots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a sequence of MATLAB figures which I want to convert to a video. The figures are composed of 2 subplots, such that each subplot contains an imshow with 2 different plots (red and green) overlayed on it, like the following:

[image]

How do I get an image of all the data contained inside each figure, so that next I can convert the sequence of images to a video with VideoWriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is:

```
im = frame2im(getframe(h));
```

Where h is the handle to your plot or axis
You can also pass an optional argument 'rect' to getframe to specify the area to capture.

Here is an example from the MathWorks on how to use getframe in a loop to record the frames. For more information type `doc getframe`

```
Z = peaks;
surf(Z)
axis tight manual
ax = gca;
ax.NextPlot = 'replaceChildren';

loops = 40;
F(loops) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);
for j = 1:loops
    X = sin(j*pi/10)*Z;
    surf(X,Z)
    drawnow
    F(j) = getframe(gcf);
end

% Play back the movie two times.

fig = figure;
movie(fig,F,2)
```